# MongoDB service failing to start under different user on Linux

Tags: linux, mongodb, permissions, startup

```
mongod was running under certain Linux ID and now needs to run under different ID.
The start command:
   mongod -vvvvv --dbpath $dbpath  --fork --rest --journal --logpath $logpath

I changed the permissions on the existing database like this:
   find /data/mongo -user XXX -ls -exec chmod --verbose a+rw {} \;

Perms now:
   -rw-rw-rw- 1 XXX qs_pbdev 16777216 Oct 24 16:56 /data/mongo/hprsui.ns

mongod startup messages:

   Wed Oct 24 16:59:27 [initandlisten] mmf open /data/mongo/hprsui.ns
   Wed Oct 24 16:59:27 [initandlisten] couldn't open /data/mongo/hprsui.ns errno:1 Operation not permitted
   Wed Oct 24 16:59:27 [initandlisten] mmf finishOpening 0 /data/mongo/hprsui.ns len:16777216


What am I doing wrong and what other permissions does mongod need?
The OS is Linux RHEL 5.3.2
thank you.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give permissions over the folder it self, not only on the existing files, since it will need to create new extents of the data files

try running command:

```
chown -R XXX /data/mongo
```

This will give ownership to the new user that you want to run mongodb with.